# How to add Error Bar to Matplotlib line plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have the following dataset which I use to plot a line plot. The plot is obtained as the `mean` of values obtained from the data. I want to add error bars to this plot which shall show the standard deviation. I have looked up to different answers but in most of them they had defined `x` and `y` explicitly, but here I calculate the plot directly from the dataframe. How to add error bar to this plot?

**Dataframe df**

```
UserId     |   date                 |-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0  
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0    
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0
```

**Code**

```
badges = ["A", "B", "C"]

for badge in badges:
  res.iloc[:,2:].mean().plot(kind='line', label = badge)
```

**Output**

[image: Output Obtained]

**EDIT (Plot for only one graph with Standard Deviation)**

```
res.iloc[:,2:].mean().plot(kind='line', label = 'A')
plt.errorbar(x = res.columns.values[:-1], y = res.iloc[:,2:].mean(),yerr = res.iloc[:,2:].std())
```

Executing this code produces the following error:

```
TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a int
```

Comment: check the confidence interval in https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

Comment: @Roim in that case I have to explicitely specify what is `x` and what is `y` which is not possible in my case as you can see from the code itself. Can you demonstrate it with the help of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your lines & error bars in the loop, you can use the `plt.errorbar()` as normal inside the loop, but using `seaborn` is a lot easier if you can get your data in the appropriate format.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2, (5, 14))).assign(badge="A"),
    pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2, (5, 14))).assign(badge="B"),
])

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

badges = ["A", "B"]
colors = ["teal", "firebrick"]

for i, badge in enumerate(badges):
    
    sub_df = df[df["badge"]==badge]
    
    sub_df.iloc[:,:-1].mean().plot(kind='line', label=badge, color=colors[i])

    plt.errorbar(
        sub_df.columns.values[:-1] + (i*0.1), # offset the second error bar a bit
        sub_df.iloc[:,:-1].mean(),
        yerr=sub_df.iloc[:,:-1].std(),
        fmt='|', ecolor='grey', elinewidth=1
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Considering I am not using a loop and plotting for only 1 graph, if I write this code for errorbar `plt.errorbar(x = res.columns.values[:-1], y = res.iloc[:,2:].mean(),yerr = res.iloc[:,2:].std())`, I get the following error `TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a int`. How to fix this?

Comment: Your sample code shows a loop. Can you edit it to show a reproducible example of the issues you're having?

Comment: I have added the EDIT at the end, please take a look.

Comment: I don't get the same error when I run the code in my answer outside the loop. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what I mean by reproducible example.