# How to aggregate values of a Dataframe by mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe consisting of the number of posts made by a user in a duration of 2 weeks (days from -7 to 7). I want to create another dataframe that should have the mean number of posts made per day. I have written the following code but it returns me a series with 1 column instead of a Dataframe. The required Dataframe should have 2 separate columns for `day` and `mean`.

**Part of Dataframe (df)**

```
UserId          Date                -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
87      2011-05-10 18:38:55.030     0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
487     2011-11-29 14:46:12.080     0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21      2012-03-02 14:35:06.867     0   1   0   1   2   0   2   2   0   1   2   2   1   3   1
```

**CODE (To obtain mean posts per day)**

```
df.iloc[:,2:].mean()
```

**Code Output**

```
-7  0
-6  0.33
-5  0.33
-4  0.33
-3  0.66
-2  0
-1  1
0   0.66
1   0
2   0.33
3   0.66
4   0.66
5   0.33
6   1
7   0.33
```

This output is correct, the only problem is that it is a series. The expected output should have 2 separate columns for `day` and `mean` as shown.

**Expected Output**

```
day mean
-7  0
-6  0.33
-5  0.33
-4  0.33
-3  0.66
-2  0
-1  1
0   0.66
1   0
2   0.33
3   0.66
4   0.66
5   0.33
6   1
7   0.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), so set new columns names is not necessary:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,2:].mean().rename_axis('day').reset_index(name='mean')
print (df1)
   day      mean
0   -7  0.000000
1   -6  0.333333
2   -5  0.333333
3   -4  0.333333
4   -3  0.666667
5   -2  0.000000
6   -1  1.000000
7    0  0.666667
8    1  0.000000
9    2  0.333333
10   3  0.666667
11   4  0.666667
12   5  0.333333
13   6  1.000000
14   7  0.333333
```

EDIT: Working with seaborn 11:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df1, x = 'day', y = 'mean', err_style="bars",ci=68)
```

Comment: This works correctly but if I use this data to plot a line plot the Standard Deviation is not visible. Can you provide a way to plot it as well?                                            
`sns.lineplot(x = df1['day'], y = df1['mean'])`

Comment: @IshanDutta - Use `sns.lineplot(data=df1, x = 'day', y = 'mean')`

Comment: I used this, but it gives me the same plot with the standard deviation.

Comment: But these are 2 different plots, in case of seaborn std should appear as confidence interval or error bar.

Comment: @IshanDutta - Unfortunately not understand, last paragraph solution not working too?

Comment: It works but it gives 2 different plots, you can considering looking here for a better insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293179/how-to-add-error-bar-to-matplotlib-line-plot

Comment: @IshanDutta - How working `sns.lineplot(data=df1, x = 'day', y = 'mean', err_style="bars",ci=68)` ?

Comment: It is still showing the same graph without the error bar.

Comment: @IshanDutta - Unfortunately not idea why :(

Comment: Even I have been trying to fix this for a long time but can't find the answer. I am accepting your answer as your solution worked for the main question i.e., obtaining mean from dataframe.

Comment: @IshanDutta - thank you, maybe question should be for matplotlib guru why `sns.lineplot(data=df1, x = 'day', y = 'mean', err_style="bars",ci=68)` show nothing, but if check [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) it working well.

Comment: Sure @jezrael . Will try some more methods and see if it works.